# ¿Cómo ordenar nombres de fichero por extensión tras leer un directorio?

Tags: java

Tengo un método que obtiene los nombres de los ficheros de un directorio, ordenados alfabéticamente, por ejemplo así:

```
aaa.txt
abb.rar
bbb.txt
x.bmp
xa.as
zz.bmp
```

Quiero poder ordenarlos primero por tipo de archivo (alfabéticamente ) y luego dentro de cada grupo alfabéticamente por nombre, es decir:

```
xa.as
x.bmp
zz.bmp
abb.rar
aaa.txt
bbb.txt
```

Mí código de partida:

```
public String[] getNames( String path ) {

            String[] arr_res = null;
            File directory   = new File( path );

            File[] arr_content = directory.listFiles();
            int len = arr_content.length;

            List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

            for ( int i = 0; i < len; i ++ ) {

                if ( arr_content[ i ].isFile( ))
                    res.add( arr_content[ i ].getName( ));
            }
            if ( res.size() > 0 )
                arr_res = res.toArray( new String[ 0 ] );


            return arr_res;
        }
```

Se me ha ocurrido extraer las extensiones de los ficheros, hacer grupos ordenados para cada una de estas y luego componer la salida. Quisiera saber si conocen alguna forma más simple y directa. Aporto mi solución con la que se pueden obtener, indistintamente, las dos listas de ficheros anteriores (perdonar por el código extra que permite obtener listado de los directorios):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Strings {

        private static List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();


        /**
         * Cleans the array of empty strings
         *
         */
        public static String[] delEmpties( String[] arr ) {

            res.clear();
            int len = arr.length;

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < len; i ++ ) {

                if ( ! arr[ i ].equals( "" ))
                    res.add( arr[ i ] );
            }


            return res.toArray( new String[ 0 ] );
        }

        /**
         * Filters the array of strings and delete repeat elements
         *
         */
        public static String[] filterRepeated( String[] arr ) {


            int len = arr.length;

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < len; i ++ ) {
                for ( int j = 0; j < ( len - 1 ); j ++ ) {

                    if ( i != j ) {
                        if ( arr[ i ].equals( arr[ j ] )) {
                            arr[ j ] = ""; //replace value by empty string
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }


            return delEmpties( arr );
        }

} //class


import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

public class ContentFilter {

    private static List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    private static String[] arr_res = null;


    /**
     * Gets the directories from the directory content
     *
     * @param   String  The directory path
     * @return  String[]
     */
    public static String[] getDirectoryNames( String path ) {

        return getNames( path, "directories" );
    }

    /**
     * Gets the files from the directory content
     *
     */
    public static String[] getFileNames( String path ) {

        return getNames( path, "files" );
    }

    /**
     * Gets the files from the directory content
     *
     */
    public static String[] getFileNames( 
        String path,
        boolean order_by_type
    ) {

        return ( order_by_type )
            ? getNamesByType( path )
            : getNames( path, "files" );
    }

    /**
     * Gets the file types from array of file names
     *
     */
    public static String[] getFileTypes( String[] names ) {

        if ( names != null ) {

            int size = names.length;
            String file_type = "";

            res.clear(); //remove previous content

            for ( int i = 0; i < size; i ++ ) {

                file_type = getFileType( names[ i ] );
                res.add( file_type );
            }

            if ( res.size() > 0 ) {
                arr_res = res.toArray( new String[ 0 ] );
                Arrays.sort( arr_res );
                arr_res = Strings.filterRepeated( arr_res );
            }
        }


        return arr_res;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the names for files / directories
     *
     */
    public static String[] getNames( String path, String type ) {

        File directory = new File( path );

        File[] arr_content = directory.listFiles();

        if ( arr_content != null ) {
            int len = arr_content.length;
            res.clear(); //remove previous content

            for ( int i = 0; i < len; i ++ ) {

                if ( type.equals( "directories" ) && arr_content[ i ].isDirectory( ))
                    res.add( arr_content[ i ].getName( ));

                if ( type.equals( "files" ) && arr_content[ i ].isFile( ))
                    res.add( arr_content[ i ].getName( ));
            }
            if ( res.size() > 0 )
                arr_res = res.toArray( new String[ 0 ] );

        } else
            System.err.println( "Err -> Sin contenido de \"" + path + "\"" );


        return arr_res;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the file types
     *
     */
    public static String[] getNamesByType( String path ) {

        String[] file_names = getNames( path, "files" );
        String[] file_types = getFileTypes( file_names );

        if ( file_types != null ) {

            //Groups file names by file extension
            Hashtable<String, String[]> groups = getGroups( 
                file_names, 
                file_types 
            );

            arr_res = getArrayFromGroups( groups );
        }


        return arr_res;
    }


    /**
     * Aux. getFileTypes()
     * Gets file type from a file name
     *
     */
    private static String getFileType( String name ) {

        int pos;
        String type = name;

        while (( pos = type.indexOf( "." )) > -1 ) {

            type = name.substring(
                pos + ".".length(),
                name.length()
            );
        }


        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Groups file names by file extension
     * 
     */
    private static Hashtable<String, String[]> getGroups( 
        String[] file_names, 
        String[] file_types 
    ) {

        int size_file_names = file_names.length;
        int size_file_types = file_types.length;

        String file_name, file_type;

        Hashtable<String, String[]> groups = new Hashtable<>();
        //groups.put( "Ciudades España", new String[] { "Madrid", "Teruel" } );


        //Iterates over file extensions
        for ( int i = 0; i < size_file_types; i ++ ) {
            res.clear();
            file_type = file_types[ i ];

            //Iterates over file names
            for ( int j = 0; j < size_file_names; j ++ ) {

                file_name = file_names[ j ];


                //Finded file extension inside the file name
                if ( file_name.indexOf( file_type ) > -1 ) {

                    res.add( file_name );
                }
            }

            groups.put( 
                file_type,
                res.toArray( new String[ 0 ] ) //String[] with file names of one type
            );
        }


        return groups;
    }

    private static String[] getArrayFromGroups(
            Hashtable<String, String[]> groups
    ) {
        res.clear();

        String[] keys = getKeys( groups ); //Gets the keys
        int keys_size = keys.length;


        for ( int i = 0; i < keys_size; i ++ ) {

            String key = keys[ i ];
            String[] temp_arr = groups.get( key );

            for ( String str : temp_arr ) {

                res.add( str );
            }
        }
        arr_res = res.toArray( new String[ 0 ] );


        return arr_res;
    }

    /**
     * Aux. getArrayFromGroups()
     *
     */
    private static String[] getKeys( 
        Hashtable<String, String[]> groups 
    ) {

        Enumeration<String> e = groups.keys();
        List<String> temp = Collections.list( e );
        String[] keys = temp.toArray( new String[ 0 ] );

        Arrays.sort( keys );


            return keys;
        }

} //class
```

Clase para trazado:

```
public class Trace {

        /**
         * Prints the strings stored into an array 
         * 
         */
        public static void strArray( String[] arr_strs, String msg ) {
            System.out.println( "Trace / strArray()" );

            System.out.println( msg );


            if ( arr_strs != null ) {

                int len = arr_strs.length;
                String str;

                for ( int i = 0; i < len; i ++ ) {

                    str = arr_strs[ i ];
                    System.out.println( str );
                }

            } else
                System.err.println( "Trace / strArray() -> Err: recibido \"null\"" );

            System.out.println( "-------------------------" );
        }

} //class
```

Clase con los test:

```
import app.helpers.ContentFilter;
import app.helpers.Strings;
import app.helpers.Trace;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test {

        static String path = "d://_test/";


        public static void main( String[] args ) {

            String[] arr1 = ContentFilter.getFileNames( path );
            String[] arr2 = ContentFilter.getFileNames( path, true );

            Trace.strArray( arr1 );
            Trace.strArray( arr2 );
        }

} //class
```

Answer (score 3):

Para practicar un poco de Java 8:

```
public class Test {

    public static class FileExt implements Comparable<FileExt> {
        final String name, ext; // ext include punto

        public FileExt(String filename) {
            int extpos = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
            this.name = extpos >= 0 ? filename.substring(0, extpos) : filename;
            this.ext = extpos >= 0 ? filename.substring(extpos) : "";
        }

        public int compareTo(FileExt other) {
            int i = ext.compareTo(other.ext);
            return i != 0 ? i : name.compareTo(other.name);
        }

    }

    public static List<String> sortFiles(List<String> files) {
        return files.stream()
                .map(f -> new FileExt(f))
                .sorted()
                .map(fe -> fe.name + fe.ext)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] files = { "aaa.txt", "abb.rar", "bbb.txt", 
              "x.bmp", "xa.as", "sinext", "emptyext.", "zz.bmp" };
        List sorted = sortFiles(Arrays.asList(files));
        System.out.println(sorted);
    }
}
```

Comparado con la solución de Lucas_Kunze esto tiene la ventaja de que la extracción de nombre y extensión se hace una sola vez, y no en cada comparación. También es más legible y funciona con archivos sin extensión (o extensión vacía).

Comment: Te felicito por tu solución: Utilizas las posibilidades de Java 1.8 al máximo. Publicaciones así son las que harán crecer a esta comunidad. Tienes mi voto.

Answer (score 2):

Puede hacerlo utilizando el comparador ArrayList. Si desea comparar con indiferencia elementos no sea sensible a mayúsculas, basta con quitar el comentario.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getNames( String path ) 
{
    File directory   = new File( path );
    File[] arr_content = directory.listFiles();
    int len = arr_content.length;

    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for ( int i = 0; i < len; i ++ ) {

        if ( arr_content[ i ].isFile( ))
            res.add( arr_content[ i ].getName( ));
    }
    res.sort(new Comparator(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
            String _o1 = (String)o1;
            String _o2 = (String)o2;
            int res;
            return (res = _o1.substring(_o1.lastIndexOf("."),_o1.length())/*.toLowerCase()*/.
                compareTo(_o2.substring(_o2.lastIndexOf(".")/*.toLowerCase()*/,_o2.length())))!=0?res:
                    _o1.substring(0,_o1.lastIndexOf("."))/*.toLowerCase()*/.compareTo(_o2.substring(0,_o2.lastIndexOf("."))/*.toLowerCase()*/);
        }
    });
    return res;
}
```

Efetuei las correcciones[2] mencionado por el amigo Awes0meM4n.

Comment: Te falta añadir también la ordenación de antes del punto y no estaría mal decir que este código sólo funciona con Java 1.8 o superior por el lambda que has metido.

Comment: Lo siento por mi falta de atención. Confieso que había leído sólo la primera parte y salidas. En cuanto al esquema de lambda, no sabía que se había introducido en Java 1.8. Gracias.

Comment: No te preocupes, cuantos más ojos haya mirando una misma cosa mejor podrá acabar :). Por otra parte, creo que ahora te falta hacer el `substring` para quitar la extensión, si no vas a tener fallos porque está contando como nombre el punto y la extensión y según entiendo debe ordenarse en una segunda parte por el nombre sin la extensión.

Comment: Creo que no es necesario eliminar el punto, ya que el orden de los nombres sólo se producirá si las extensiones son los mismos, cambiando sólo entre sí, no cambiando el orden de los demás.

Comment: No dan el mismo resultado. Imagina ordenar "a1.doc" y "a11.doc". Cualquiera de nosotros diría que el 11 está después, pero la computadora cuando llegue a la posición 2 (en base 0) va a comparar un "1" contra un ".". Si hubieras quitado la extensión habría terminado la comparación en ese punto porque el primer archivo no tienes un índice 2. Por eso el resultado no tiene porqué ser el esperado.

Comment: Realmente yo no había pensado en esa posibilidad.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Observa las posibilidades de extensiones de archivo en mi respuesta. He tratado de darle fastidio al método poniendo extensiones raras en el `arrFiles` ... y ordena perfectamente. :)

Comment: Amigo, su respuesta no puede ordenar a la segunda parte requerida por el interrogador. Tenga en cuenta que el cambio "a.txt", "b.txt" por "b.txt", "a.txt" genera una ordenación incorreta. [Ideone](http://ideone.com/3Fj1hd)

Answer (score 0):

> ## Actualizado: solución definitiva

Traté de hacerlo con `ArraySort` pero por más vueltas que le daba no encontraba la forma de hacer una **doble** comparación, 1º por la extensión y 2º por el nombre, así que una forma de resolverlo es a través de **una comparación concatenada**.

La idea es : desde una clase que almacena por separado el nombre y la extensión del objeto `Archivo` comparar y ordenar primero por la extensión y luego por el nombre.

Lo bueno es que esta clase puede servir para concatenar dos comparaciones cualesquiera usando dos o más criterios (bastaría con añadir más comparaciones posibles y adaptarla):

La ordenación se hace correctamente, incluso en los **posibles** casos de **archivos sin extensión** o **"sin nombre"**... como es el caso de .htaccess.

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/s0qQgI)**

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Archivo 
{
    private String nombre;
    private String extension;

    public Archivo (String nombre, String extension) 
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    // getters y setters
    public String getNombre() 
    {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getExtension() 
    {
        return extension;
    }


    public String toString() 
    {
return nombre + "." + extension;
    }
}


class ArchivoComparadorCadena implements Comparator<Archivo> 
    {

    private List<Comparator<Archivo>> listComparators;

    @SafeVarargs
    public ArchivoComparadorCadena(Comparator<Archivo>... comparators) 
    {
        this.listComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Archivo nom1, Archivo nom2) 
    {
        for (Comparator<Archivo> comparator : listComparators) 
        {
            int result = comparator.compare(nom1, nom2);
            if (result != 0) 
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
        }
    }


/**
 * Este comparador compara dos archivos por su extensión.
 * @author a.cedano
 *
 */
class ExtensionComparator implements Comparator<Archivo> 
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Archivo nom1, Archivo nom2) 
    {
        return nom1.getExtension().compareTo(nom2.getExtension());
    }
}


class NombreComparator implements Comparator<Archivo> 
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Archivo nom1, Archivo nom2) 
    {
        return nom1.getNombre().compareTo(nom2.getNombre());
    }
}


/**
 * Este programa demuestra cómo ordenar una colección
 * por múltiples atributos usando un comparador encadenado.
 *
 * @author a.cedano
 *
 */
class OrdenandoAtributosMultiples 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<Archivo> listArchivos = new ArrayList<Archivo>();
        listArchivos.add(new Archivo("a", "txt"));
        listArchivos.add(new Archivo("a", "pdf"));
        listArchivos.add(new Archivo("z", "txt"));
        listArchivos.add(new Archivo("aa1", "txt" ));
        listArchivos.add(new Archivo("a1", "pdf" ));
        listArchivos.add(new Archivo("", "htaccess" ));
        listArchivos.add(new Archivo("ext con", " espacio" ));
        listArchivos.add(new Archivo("", "sinnombre" ));
        listArchivos.add(new Archivo("zzzz", "@!!" ));

        System.out.println("*** Antes de ordenar: ***");

        for (Archivo archivos : listArchivos) 
        {
            System.out.println(archivos);
        }

        // Aquí ordenamos primero por extensión, luego por nombre

        Collections.sort(listArchivos, new ArchivoComparadorCadena(
            new ExtensionComparator(),
            new NombreComparator())
        );

        System.out.println("\n*** Después de ordenar: ***");

        for (Archivo archivos : listArchivos) 
        {
            System.out.println(archivos);
        }

    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

> ```
> *** Antes de ordenar: ***
> a.txt
> a.pdf
> z.txt
> aa1.txt
> a1.pdf
> .htaccess
> ext con. espacio
> .sinnombre
> zzzz.@!!
>
> *** Después de ordenar: ***
> ext con. espacio
> zzzz.@!!
> .htaccess
> a.pdf
> a1.pdf
> .sinnombre
> a.txt
> aa1.txt
> z.txt
> ```

Comment: El problema de tu solución es que sólo ordena por extensión y no por el nombre sin extensión. Además según lo has implementado creo que te puede dar una excepción por incumplimiento del contrato.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n He actualizado el código con una solución que funciona y que además puede servir en múltiples casos.

Comment: Está bien, pero la de @leonbloy no tiene rival. Lo bueno de la tuya es que puede usarse sin Java 8. El problema que la veo ahora es que has separado la entrada en nombre y extensión, pero el OP tiene una lista de nombres de archivos incluyendo la extensión así que te falta eso para estar completa. No obstante, yo ya te di un voto positivo porque la anterior era correcta. Si te ves con cero es porque alguien te ha dado uno negativo.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Ya. La ventaja es que, como se trata de una Clase, el OP o cualquiera con un mínimo conocimiento de Java podría modificarla, creando por ejemplo métodos que reciban diferentes tipos de valores. La Clase se puede adaptar para hacer cualquier tipo de comparación doble, o triple o cuádruple...